# Keyboard extension: "Message=Service Connection Interrupted"

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I wrote a keyboard extension and met some problems. I put a collectview on this extension. collectview every cell needs to load a GIF diagram, each GIF dynamic figure is 2 m, then there is the keyboard crash case, an error for the following reasons (). I have been in the info. The file of RequestsOpenAccess set to YES. So I don't know where the problem is. The following is the cause of the error, only these:

> 2017-03-24 21:37:45.820834 ExpressionBaby[3672:934876] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
>   2017-03-24 21:37:48.709876 ExpressionBaby[3672:934876] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
>   2017-03-24 21:37:49.222492 ExpressionBaby[3672:934876] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
>   2017-03-24 21:37:51.231664 ExpressionBaby[3672:934876] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
>   2017-03-24 21:37:53.225378 ExpressionBaby[3672:934876] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
>   2017-03-24 21:37:54.500931 ExpressionBaby[3672:934876] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
>   2017-03-24 21:37:55.016598 ExpressionBaby[3672:934876] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

Comment: Please share the code that is triggering this error

Comment: I have also been having that problem and seems like a generic error. First I was getting it because I didn't fully configured the collection view (data source not implemented), then it was happen if I have a breakpoint before the keyboard initializes fully. It won't happen if I don't have a breakpoint.

Comment: hey , me again, I solved it before (I guess), but I need the answer again 